# Enable selecting text without user interaction enabled

Tags: swift, uitextfield, user-interaction

I have a text field with the phone number in it. It should not be edited, but the user should have an ability to select it by long pressing on the phone. When he long presses text should get selected, not just copied to the clipboard. So far I only got it to work with `isUserInteractionEnabled == true` but I need to still have it false. Any suggestion on how I could do this? My code now:

```
func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    self.cell?.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.cell?.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.cell?.textField.selectedTextRange = self.cell?.textField.textRange(from: (self.cell?.textField.beginningOfDocument)!, to: (self.cell?.textField.endOfDocument)!)
    //self.cell?.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false? Is it just to disable editing? Cause for that there is a different property.

Comment: set the textfiled editing property false and UserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: I wish both of you guys could also mention what the property is. The only one that sounds like something you mention is `isEditing` which is something else and get only.

Comment: @ЧингизМарданов I just realised you are using a `UITextField`. Don't use it if you want to disable editing. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes, `UITextField` is not a suitable choice. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield?changes=latest_minor) states, `UITextField` is (emphasis added by me):

> An object that displays an **editable** text area in your interface.

Hence, you cannot set a `UITextField` to be non-editable. If you want to display text on the UI, which shouldn't be editable, use a `UILabel` or `UITextView`.

You can set the `UITextView`'s `isEditable` property to false and it will still be selectable as long as `isSelectable` is set to true.

A `UILabel` displays read only text, so you don't even need to take care of disabling editing when using it.

Comment: I guess changing to `UITextView` is my only option here. Thanks.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe setting `isEnabled` to false disables touches as well, so that is not a feasible solution for just disabling editing. See the documentation: _"Set the value of this property to true to enable the control or false to disable it. An enabled control is capable of responding to user interactions, whereas a disabled control ignores touch events and may draw itself differently."_